# Jquery mouse-over fade-in/out (best practices)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got working Jquery code to fade in/out descriptive text in a div below the question. The problem? The solution is not very elegant. Here's what I've got:

```
$("#home").mouseover(function() {
    $("#homeText").fadeIn("slow");
});
$("#homeText").mouseout(function() {
    $("#homeText").fadeOut();
});
```

I know there is better way to do this, I'm just not sure what it is.

Comment: perhaps you could describe what about this code troubles you.  Why do you think it isn't elegant?

Answer (score 22):

you could use hover, the first function will act on a "hover over" and the second will act on a "hover out"

The documentation is located here: http://docs.jquery.com/Events/hover

```
$("#home").hover(function(){
    $("#homeText").fadeIn("slow");
},
function(){
    $("#homeText").fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: Great advice! I built on your solution and modified to work on an arbitrary number of elements without redundant code:
$('.topMenu').hover(function()
    {
   $('#_'+this.id).fadeIn("slow");
   },
   function ()
    {
   $('#_'+this.id).fadeOut();  
    });
 });

Answer (score 7):

How about 3 lines?

```
<script>

    $(function () {

        $('#home').hover(function() {
           $('#homeText').fadeToggle("slow");
        });

    });


    </script>
```

Elegant enough?

Answer (score 2):

Jon, Great advice! I used as a staring point though for a more complete solution. Doing this with just the basic hover would still leave me with a hover call for single menu item..A lot of redundant code. So using what you suggested, I came up with this:

```
$('.topMenu').hover(function()
        {
        $('#_'+this.id).fadeIn("slow");
        },
        function ()
            {
        $('#_'+this.id).fadeOut();      
            });
});
```

All menu items are given the topMenu class and ID. The corresponding div to display is the same id as the menu item, just prefixed with _
Example:

....

Stuff about us!

...

Thanks!

Comment: definately, customize to your own needs. glad to have helped =)

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function () {
    $('#home').hover(function() {
       $('#homeText').fadeIn("slow");
    });
    $('#home').mouseout(function() {
       $('#homeText').fadeOut("slow");
    });
});
```